# What does it mean for $\operatorname{Ad}_g(-)$ to be trivial on commutative Hopf algebra $H$?

Tags: hopf-algebras

Just curious, what does it mean for the adjoint action to be trivial on a commutative Hopf algebra $H$? Does it mean $\operatorname{Ad}_g(f)=\epsilon(g)f$, where $\epsilon$ is the counit, or $\operatorname{Ad}_g(f)=f$?

If $H$ is commutative as an algebra with antipode $S$, then I computed
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_g(f)=\sum g_1fSg_2=\sum g_1Sg_2 f=\epsilon(g)f
$$
so I suspect it's the former, but that doesn't seem like a truly "trivial" action like the latter.

Comment: That looks correct to me. It is a pretty trivial action. For most $g$ (e.g. $g$ primitive) it is $0$.